# Dialog box load - TypeError: $(...) is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a problem with my jQuery. I have managed to open a dialog window using the UI library. However, I am seeing the error:

> TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function common-jquery.js:87

I believe it may be something to do with the **load** part of my code but I am unsure why this is causing a problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // function for listening for clicks on apply buttons
    $(document).on('click', '[name*="apply"]', function() {
        var $the_dialog = $(this).create_new_dialog();

        // open the dialog and load the page.
        $the_dialog.dialog('open')
        .load('test.py', function() {
            $the_dialog.unbind('click');
            //alert('Page has loaded');
            $the_dialog.dialog('close');
        });

        return false;
    });
});

jQuery.fn.extend({

    create_new_dialog: function() {
        var $the_dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .dialog({
                // dialog box options...
                autoOpen: false,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                dialogClass: 'no-close',
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 500,
                width: 500,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Close",
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }]
            });
        return $the_dialog;
    }
});
```

When ever I click on the close button, I get the error. However, if I encapsulate the close inside of a **setTimeout** block, the dialog window disappears but I am then unable to use any of the javascript/jQuery elsewhere on the page.

I would appreciate any light you might be able to shed on this error.

Comment: Which libraries are included in your code? Include both `jQuery` and `jQuery-ui` library.

Comment: I have jQuery version 2.1.3 and jQuery-ui version 1.11.4

I have them both included in the head of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to insert full version of jQuery UI. Also you should init the dialog first:

```
$(function () {
  $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});

$("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
  });
});
```